# Format float with given precision ignoring trailing zeros

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a way to `format!` a `var: f64` with a given precision `prec`.

I know I can `format!("{:1$}", var, prec)`. Problem is, given `var=3.1` and `prec=3`, I'll get `"3.100"` as output. I'm looking for a way to omit those trailing zeros, so when `var=3.1` output is `"3.1"`, `3.0 => "3"` and `3.14159 => "3.142"`.

Is there a not so hard way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean "trailing zeroes" instead of "leading zeroes"? Also `f64`'s `3.1` may be actually not exactly `3.1`, just some approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean "trailing zeroes", you can use my library [float_pretty_print](https://docs.rs/float-pretty-print/latest/float_pretty_print/). It attains output similar to what you want by running standard float formatter multiple times and choosing the appropriate output. You can set minimum and maximum width.

```
$ cargo run --example=repl
Type number to be formatted using float_pretty_print
Also type `width=<number>` or `prec=<number>` to set width or precision.
3.1
3.1
3.12345
3.12345
prec=5
3.1
3.1
3.12345
3.123
width=5
3.1
3.100
```

Note that instead of precision, you set maximum width in characters of the whole output (not just the fractional).

Also do not expect high performance - the library may allocate multiple times for processing one number.